# Get VPN IP address via WMI on Vista

Tags: wmi, windows-vista, vpn

How can we enumerate all the network connections in order to extract the IP address of the VPN connection using WMI? On XP, Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration works fine but on Vista it only seems to enumerate the physical connections...

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the comments under the documentation for [Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394217%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) you'll see a reference to [Win32_NetworkAdapter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394216%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) when dealing with Vista.

```
'Vista only code???
Set colAdapters = objWMIService.Execquery ("SELECT * FROM Win32_NetworkAdapter WHERE NetEnabled = True")
For Each nic in colAdapters
    msg = "nic.DeviceId: " & nic.DeviceId & vbCRLF _
    & "nic.Name: " & nic.Name & vbCRLF _
Next
```

From this you should be able to retreive the **InterfaceIndex** and lookup the IP address from the [Win32_IP4RouteTable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394162%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) class.

It certainly is a roundabout way of getting the information compared to using **Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration**.

Answer (score 0):

Found it in the MSFT classes! Windows Specific implementation of CIM interface object:
gwmi msft_netIPAddress -Namespace 'root/standardcimv2' | format-list -Property InterfaceAlias,IPAddress